# TimeSpan and "24:00" parse error in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parsing, model-binding, timespan

I have a modal dialog in my web application where users are able to enter a time range between 00:00 and 24:00. A range slider is used to select this range.

Everything works as expected except that whenever user sets the right range handle to have a value of 24:00 default model binder can't parse this `TimeSpan`.

```
public class Timing
{
    public TimeSpan Starts { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Ends { get; set; }
}
```

My object that gets sent back to server has an `IList<Timing>` property.

So. The problem is just that string value "24:00" can't be parsed to `TimeSpan` instance. Is it possible to convince default model binder to recognise such string value?

I would like to avoid changing 24:00 on the client to 00:00. I know that I have `Starts` and `Ends` properties but my model validation validates that `Ends` is always greater than `Starts`. Manual changing to 23:59 is also cumbersome. **Basically is it possible to pass 24:00 and still get parsed on the server**.

Comment: How does your slider work? Does it just allow them to choose an integer from `0` to `24`? Or does it let them choose a time (with minutes)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the range is fractionally too large. `24:00` is in fact `00:00` the next day.
so they should go from `00:00.00` to `23:59.99` or whatever.

**FINAL ANSWER(?) Change `24:00` on the client to `1.0:00`.
This will work because `TimeSpan.Parse("1.0:00").TotalHours` returns `24`**

**EDIT:** See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx. It shows the maximum range for days, hours, mins, etc. For hours it's `0` to `23` as per my comment below.

EDIT: If you are just letting them choose an integer for hours, then parse it on the server.

eg. `TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(24)`
returns `1.00:00:00`
And of course you can always say `ts.TotalHours` and it returns `24`.

Comment: I believe it would be one day precisely (so potentially expressed as `1:00:00.00`).

Comment: @Dommer: Range slider lets them choose hours and minutes between 00:00 and 24:00. But I suppose the easiest thing to do here is to change 24:00 on the client to 00:00. My ranges may therefore be inverted but I suppose I can live with that.

Comment: You should still be able to keep it as 00:00 to 24:00. But if you have some kind of special timerange slider, 24:00 would be represented as `1.0:00:00`. Is it possible for you to change `24:00` to `1.0:00:00` on the client? Then it would bind as 1 day and the rest would be as I already described. I will update my answer...

Comment: @Dommer: Changing 24:00 to 1.0:00 is somehow human unreadable. If someone would present me with a string like that I'm sure I'd need some time (and guessing) what it means. The thing is that my range slider displays values valuable to users. Anyway. I accepted your answer because it provided the most insight into the problem and helped me decide which option is the most optimal.

Comment: Thanks. You could always show `24:00` but send `1.00:00` to the server and let it parse it using one of the methods I mentioned. It must be possible to show the user one thing in the UI, but to send something else behind the scenes. Another possibility is to have the value as a string and then parse it on the server. Or to override the default model binder (e.g. a bit like this, but obviously different for your requirements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414923/can-i-validate-http-request-signature-tokens-and-nonces-using-model-binding/6418343#6418343)

Comment: @Dummer: Exactly. That's exactly what I'm doing right now. :) We'd make a good development team since we think in a similar way. :)

Comment: Lol at calling me Dummer! But yes, I agree and we are interested in the same technology stack and style of working. Maybe we should get a room (just kidding). If you are ever in the UK you should give me a shout.

Comment: @Dommer: Sorry for the laughable typo... ;)

Answer (score 2):

do a pre-processing

```
strText.Replace("24:", "00:")
```

Comment: Preprocessing is probably the only way of making this work. It's just that I+ll have to drop model validation for `Starts < Ends`.

Comment: Yup, i couldnt think of any other easy way of doing this

Comment: Sucks if you user selects 1:24:24 as their time

Comment: Format here is Hours:Minutes not Hours:Minutes:seconds

Comment: That's right. So give by your example it's impossible for minutes to get converted to zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Limit the value of the end to 23:59

24:00 == 00:00 the next day

Comment: It is yes. but when calculating time difference between (24:00 - 00:00) is much more different than (00:00 - 00:00). One being 24 hours the other being zero.

Comment: Yes but in that case when you subtract one timespan from the other you would get 1 day (as it would be 1 day exactly minus nothing).

Comment: @Dommer: Which case? 24:00 - 00:00 would give you one day... But converting 24:00 to 00:00 on the client (so model binding on the server will work) will give you 00:00 - 00:00 = 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes... Which isn't correct...

Comment: But in that case you are changing it too early (and to the wrong value). I have updated my answer with something that should work and will enable you to change the value on the client (so they can still choose `24:00` and you will change it).