# C# WPF using 24 hour duration

Tags: c#, wpf

Im creating a WPF application and just wondering is there a way to use 24 hour duration. Right now my code looks like this:

```
<DoubleAnimation x:Name="Animation"
      Storyboard.TargetName="hourHandTransform"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
      Duration="12:0:0" RepeatBehavior="Forever" To="360"/>
```

I tried setting the duration to 24 like this:

```
<DoubleAnimation x:Name="hourAnimation"
      Storyboard.TargetName="hourHandTransform"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
      Duration="24:0:0" RepeatBehavior="Forever" To="360"/>
```

But this gave me a error..
And when running the application il get:

Or maybe somebody have some good ideas how do create animation with duration of 24 hours?

Comment: What am I missing, what's wrong with that?  If you're getting an exception what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duration is a TimeSpan object (see MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.duration.timespan.aspx)

This being so, you should use `Duration="1.0:00"`

See my answer here for more: [TimeSpan and "24:00" parse error in Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415473/timespan-and-2400-parse-error-in-asp-net-mvc/6415513#6415513)

In summary: `TimeSpan.Parse("1.0:00").TotalHours` returns `24`

Comment: It is a bit odd that you can't specify a duration of 24 hours directly and it's tripped up quite a few people (including me) before. Glad to have saved you a bit of hassle.